# Pass windows environmental variables to dockerized python app

Tags: python, docker, environment-variables

I am running a python application that reads two paths from Windows env vars and proceeds to use the executables in those paths to do OCR on some documents. Since POPPLER, TESSERACT env vars are already set in Windows, this Python snippet works for me:

```
popplerPath = os.environ.get('POPPLER')
tesseractPath = os.environ.get('TESSERACT')
```

Now I am trying to dockerize the app, and, to my understanding, since my container will need access to those paths, I need to mount them using VOLUME during run. My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7.7-slim
WORKDIR ./
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY documents/ .
COPY src/ ./src
CMD [ "python", "./src/run.py" ]
```

I build the image using:

```
docker build -t ocr .
```

And I try to run my container using:

```
docker run -v %POPPLER%:%POPPLER% -v %TESSERACT%:%TESSERACT% ocr
```

... but my app still gets a None value for these paths and can't use the executable files. Is my approach correct and beyond that, is it a good dev practice?

Comment: I believe %POPPLER% retrieves a Windows environment variable  with the name POPPLER, which I am trying to mount (at least through cmd it does). My goal is to mount the path that is already set by the user

Answer (score 2):

See the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/), the switch for environment variable is `-e`:

```
$ docker run -e MYVAR1 --env MYVAR2=foo --env-file ./env.list ubuntu bash
```

and in [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), you can use

```
ENV FOO=/bar
```

If I understand your statement correctly, your paths are mounted in the container in the same path as the host. The only problem is your Python script, which expects the paths to be provided by the environment variable. This will not exist unless you pass on them from your host system to your container system.

Once you verified your mounted volume with `-v` is there correctly, you can try with

```
docker run -v %POPPLER%:%POPPLER% -v %TESSERACT%:%TESSERACT% --env POPPLER=%POPPLER% --env TESSERACT=%TESSERACT% ocr
```

or, if you always run this, you can consider to put them in your dockerfile to save some keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

Any executable you call must be built into the image.  Containers can't usually call executables on the host or in other containers.  In the specific example you show, a Linux container can't run a Windows executable, even if you do use a bind mount to inject it into the container.

The "slim" [`python` images](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) are built on Debian GNU/Linux, and you need to use its APT tool to install these executable dependencies in your Dockerfile.  (https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages has a search box to help you find the right package name; Ubuntu Linux also uses Debian packages.)

```sh
FROM python:3.7-slim
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install -y \
      popper-utils \
      tesseract-ocr-all
COPY requirements.txt .
...
```

I'd suggest putting reasonable defaults in your code if these environment variables aren't set.  The `apt-get install` command will put them in the system path inside the image.

```python
popplerPath = os.environ.get('POPPLER', 'poppler')
tesseractPath = os.environ.get('TESSERACT', 'tesseract')
```

If you really need them as environment variables you could use the Dockerfile `ENV` directive

```sh
ENV POPPLER=poppler TESSERACT=tesseract
```

Environment variables from the host don't automatically get passed through to the container; you need a Dockerfile `ENV` or `docker run -e` option.  Also remember that the container has an isolated filesystem (and Windows-syntax paths don't make sense in Linux containers) so these environment variables would need to be container paths, the second half of your proposed `docker run -v` option.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I am currently using 'subprocess' to run the executables within the python code, so I if I understand correctly, I can either slightly modify my code  to run on Linux containers (poppler/tesseract execution), or I guess switch to Windows containers and proceed with binding?

Comment: To reiterate, building an image that's missing parts of its executable code isn't a best practice.  Build these tools into the image, do not use bind mounts to inject them.